# check if a variable is null then set length to default value 0 in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects as below :

```
var data = [{country:"Austria", "customer name":"tech comp", order:"123"},
{country:"China", "customer name":"hk", order:"1111"},
{country:"UK", "customer name":"dev tech", order:"22"},
{country:"United State", "customer name":"technology", order:null} ];
```

I want to loop through each property, check the longest string and return number of characters.

For expample : on the property `country`, `United State` is the longest string among `Austria, China and Uk` so we return its length which is 12.
The same for other properties `customer name` and `order`.

The problem is when a property has `null` value. I receive the error `Cannot read property 'length' of null"`

I tried adding `x => x[key].length || 0`  so it should count length if not then 0 but not working.

Also inside the `map` I added an if block `if (x[key] != null) { x => x[key].length } else { x => 0 ; }` but not working.

Any suggestions please how can add a condition for example if the value is null then the default length is 0 so that my code could work properly ? Thank you very much.

```js
var data = [
{country:"Austria", "customer name":"tech comp", order:"123"},
{country:"China", "customer name":"hk", order:"1111"},
{country:"UK", "customer name":"dev tech", order:"22"},
{country:"United State", "customer name":"technology", order:null} ];

const longestValue = (key, array) => Math.max(...array.map(x => x[key].length));

 $.each(data[0], function(key){
console.log(key);
console.log(longestValue(key, data));
      
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`const longestValue = (key, array) => Math.max(...array.map(x => x[key]?.length || 0));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to coerce a truthy value of your map query here with this:

```
...array.map(x => x[key] && x[key].length)
```

This should first check if x[key] is true/has a length and then return false if not. This should prevent the error from being thrown.

A classic if (x[key]) { ....} where you return if x[key] has a falsy value would also work but is a bit ugly inside of a map.